# Use of non-ascii strings in defining z3 variablels and types

Tags: python, z3, non-ascii-characters

I am defining `z3` varialbes and types in `z3py`, like `X=Int('X')` or `X=EnumSort('X',['Y',...])` in case `X,Y,...` are non-ascii character strings, in my case, Japanese.

My system is `Python3.7.6` and `z3py 4.8.7.0` on `MacOs 10.15.7`. The response from the system is,

```py
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/z3/z3core.py", line 1588, in Z3_mk_string_symbol
    r = _elems.f(a0, _str_to_bytes(a1))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

How can I solve the problem? For the variable case, I found a trick `X=Int('X'.encode())`, though this did not work for `EnumSort`.

Comment: Not famiiar with `z3py` but in Python 3 strings are Unicode and should handle any code point, so it seems like a bug in `z3py`, esp. since the failure was on a `_str_to_bytes` function.  Perhaps it isn't using UTF-8 for the conversion, but some legacy encoding?

Comment: Thank you for your commenting. I am inclined to think so.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, though you might have to set the appropriate encoding settings on your terminal to print the characters correctly.

(Also, apologies in advance if these characters have non-appropriate meanings! I don't speak Chinese unfortunately, and I merely copied them off of the internet.)

```py
# coding=utf-8

from z3 import *

E, _ = EnumSort('的', ['是', '不'])

s = Solver()
a = Const('X', E)
b = Const('Y', E)
s.add(a != b)

if s.check() == sat:
   m = s.model()
   for i in [a, b]:
     print(repr(m[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. Your script, however, did not work on my system and returned the same error message.

Comment: I think it really depends on your terminal settings, OS settings, Locale settings, etc. This question really has less to do with z3py than to how Python, your OS, your terminal etc. handles those settings. I recommend asking directly to the Python folks using a non-z3 example if you can. That might attract more relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem: `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2: invalid continuation byte`.

The following code in z3core.py (line 69) is highly dubious to me:

```
def _str_to_bytes(s):
  if isinstance(s, str):
    try:
      return s.encode('latin-1')
    except:
      # kick the bucket down the road.  :-J
      return s
  else:
    return s
```

Maybe it's a left-over from python2.  If I change `latin-1` to `utf-8`, it seems to work... but that's more a hack than a good solution.  Maybe we need to submit a patch.  I raised [an issue](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/4956) on the Z3 github repository.

Comment: I can reproduce the OP error when I ask _str_to_bytes to return s directly.  So, changing latin-1 to utf-8 may fix the OP problem too.

Comment: I followed your instruction and made a patch to my z3core.py, and found my problem has been solved. Hope your raising the issue is taken and I can forget the patch for my next update of z3-solver. Thank you so much !